# CMake cannot follow symlinks on Windows 10

Tags: windows, build, cmake, filesystems

In my CMakeLists.txt I am trying to install a folder which contains symlinks. It works well on windows 7 before, but after switching to windows 10 it is broken. By narrowing down the problem I figured out the symlink on windows 10 might be the root cause. 
I wrote a small piece of cmake to test it:

```
file(GLOB all_files *)
foreach(each_file ${all_files})
    if (IS_SYMLINK ${each_file})
        get_filename_component(each_file_real_path ${each_file} REALPATH)
    endif()
endforeach()
```

If I run above cmake scripts inside a folder with symlinks inside, the `IS_SYMLINK` works correctly but `get_filename_component(REALPATH)` always return the same input path instead of the real path.

Is there any way to fix or work around it? Thanks!

Comment: Are the same symlinks from Win7 in Win10?

Comment: @joel Using dir to list all files in the directory. It looks like the link types are the same.

Comment: @HaoCS any update on this issue? Did you work around the problem? If so, how? (maybe provide this as an answer)

Comment: @macetw Nope. I gave up and copy files instead of using symlinks.

Comment: @HaoCS Have you tried this on the latest version of CMake (3.14.4)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the symlink one level deeper, pointing at a directory one level higher. Cmake won't have a problem if the directory-symlink is up a level from where you're pointing.

This is just a workaround. There's still a definitive bug in cmake at this point.