# CMake cannot follow symbolic links

Tags: cmake

Update: turns out the problem is not related to the Jenkins agent but to CMake. It is easily reproducible from the command line. 
It was reported here once before:
[CMake cannot follow symlinks on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690894/cmake-cannot-follow-symlinks-on-windows-10)
However, the problem is not OS-related. We encounter it on Linux also.

I'm debugging the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/jenkins/trial/workspace/WWB6-6.13.0/wwb-Pilot_Build_BB/wwb6/build/cmake_install.cmake:48 (file):
 file INSTALL cannot read symlink
  "C:/jenkins/trial/workspace/WWB6-6.13.0/wwb6-Build-Pilot-Windows/wwb6/wwb6/HelpFiles"
to duplicate at
  "C:/jenkins/trial/workspace/WWB6-6.13.0/wwb6-Build-Pilot-Windows/wwb6/build/_CPack_Packages/win64/NSIS/WWB6 Setup/./Help".
```

The relevant line in the make file is:

```
file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/./Help" TYPE DIRECTORY FILES "C:/jenkins/trial/workspace/WWB6-6.13.0/wwb-Pilot_Build_BB/wwb6/wwb6/HelpFiles/")
```

The intent is to copy the contents of the HelpFiles directory into a new directory "Help" in the workspace. The HelpFiles directory in this scenario is a symbolic link to another directory in the source repository:

```
Directory of C:\jenkins\trial\workspace\WWB6-6.13.0\wwb6-Build-Pilot-Windows\wwb6\wwb6
05/17/2019  03:09 PM    <SYMLINKD>     HelpFiles [..\helpwwb6]
```

Traversing this symlink from the command line works fine:

```
C:\jenkins\trial\workspace\WWB6-6.13.0\wwb6-Build-Pilot-Windows\wwb6\wwb6>cd HelpFiles
C:\jenkins\trial\workspace\WWB6-6.13.0\wwb6-Build-Pilot-Windows\wwb6\wwb6\HelpFiles>
```

Anyone know of a workaround for this problem? The version of CMake we're running is 3.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, there's an easy (although not elegant) workaround for this: replace the symlink with the real path in the CMakeLists file:

```
install ( DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../helpwwb6/
      DESTINATION ${BINARY_INSTALL_LOCATION}/Help
      COMPONENT Runtime
      PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
      PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE
    )
```

Would rather see CMake work with symlinks though.